# Avoiding circular reference in Python on type hinting for classes referencing each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, circular-dependency, type-hinting, circular-reference

I'm writing two classes, `Parent` and `Child`, so that the parent contains several children and each child contains a reference to the parent to eventually invoke its `method()`. Since I use *type hinting* (**PIP 484**, mainly for clarity and readability of the code), I come up with the error:

```
ValueError: Circular reference detected
```

due to the fact that `example/child.py` imports `Parent` already defined in `example/parent.py`. **Does anyone know how to get rid of this error?**

My `Parent` (in `example/parent.py`) is as follows:

```
from typing import List
from example.child import Child

class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, children: List[Child] = None) -> None:
        self._children = \
            {child.name: child for child in children} if children else {}

    @property
    def children(self) -> List[Child]:
        return list(self._children.values())

    @children.setter
    def children(self, value: List[Child] = None) -> None:
        self._children = {child.name: child for child in value} if value else {}

    def new_child(self, name: str) -> Child:
        child = Child(self, name)
        self._children[name] = child
        return child

    def method(self) -> bool:
        return len(self._children) % 2 == 0
```

My `Child` (in `example/child.py`), instead, is as follows:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, List

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from example.parent import Parent

class Child(object):
    def __init__(self, parent: 'Parent', name: str) -> None:
        if parent is None:
            raise ValueError("'parent' is invalid: <%s>" % parent)
        if name is None or not str(name).strip():
            raise ValueError("'name' is invalid: <%s>" % name)
        self._parent = parent
        self._name = str(name).strip()

    @property
    def parent(self) -> 'Parent':
        return self._parent

    @property
    def name(self) -> str:
        return self._name

    def method(self) -> None:
        print('we are even' if self._parent.method() else 'we are odd')
```

Notice that I already introduced the trick which consists in using the `TYPE_CHECKING` variable, but in this case it doesn't help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you `import Parent` in `child.py`? As you're already doing, you can use the class *name*, as a string, as the type hint.

Comment: Because PyCharm suggests that I have an `Unresolved reference 'Parent': more...`

Comment: I removed the import and I obtain the same `ValueError: Circular reference detected` (with a different stack trace, though).

Comment: Did you try to execute the code before flagging it as duplicate?
I had slightly more complex classes, I'm going to try with the very same as above now...

Comment: The simplified version works fine, I'll figure out what it's failing on the full code... many thanks for your help!